# How to change the icon of collapse component using ExpandIcon in ANT Design with blazor/.NET

Tags: c#, html, .net, blazor, antd

```html
<Collapse ExpandIcon={({ isActive })=>
                    isActive ? <Icon Type="plus" Theme="outline" /> : <Icon Type="minus" Theme="outline" />} >
```

What is isActive here, I got this snippet from another question of this site and how to get values for isActive.

Please give Code examples and idea to get which key is collapsed

Comment: i am guessing its a bool that determines if the element is selected

Comment: I don't think that other question was about Blazor. Add a Link so we can see.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.